# Who succeeded Tessio after his execution?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

After Tessio was executed for setting Michael up, who took over his territory?

Answer (score -1):

Although Tessio (and Clemenza) indeed wanted to go independent when Vito retired, they would only be allowed so upon Corleone's move to Nevada.

So, when Tessio refers to his "territory" in Brooklyn when talking to Michael about the proposed "meeting" with Barzini, that was merely his land property (as opposed to a crime domain under his control). He was still Corleone's caporegime, not an independent crime boss.

Presumably, upon Tessio's execution, his Brooklyn property became his heirs' (if he actually owned it and had heirs). Otherwise, it remained Corleone's, and was given to Clemenza (and then to Frank Pentangeli) after the move to Nevada.

Comment: Have you anything to back this up? I think it would be interesting. I've always asked myself who was Tessio's successor but found nothing.

Comment: @OldPadawan If we're talking about his legal successors (estate heirs), the movie says nothing about them as far as I remember (not sure about the novel though). Indeed, why bother the audience with such an immaterial detail? But if we're talking about his criminal domain, the movie is clear in that he had nothing on his own, and all the New York family business went to Clemenza/Pentangeli.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the criminal part: if it is said/written somewhere that Michael Corleone named someone. Just wondering :)